# Can't generate thumbnails in Nautilus

Tags: video, thumbnails

Before I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04, thumbnails on video files worked nicely, after the upgrade, thumbnails aren't generating on video files and only on video files, most of them are .mkv files. I have some .pdf files and they all have thumbnails. I have tried to clear the thumb cache, but no luck.

Comment: Isn't there a setting for size as well? Maybe thumbnails aren't being shown for (very) large files?

Answer (score 16):

Please ensure that the necessary packages are installed by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly totem libxine1-ffmpeg
```

Also, please delete the thumbnails that failed to load by running the following command:

```
rm ~/.thumbnails/fail/gnome-thumbnail-factory/*
```

In Ubuntu 13.10, the folder changes to: .cache/thumbnails, so you should delete those failed files instead:

```
rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/fail/gnome-thumbnail-factory/*
```

Comment: Just getting these packages worked for me, without no need to delete any thumbnails. Thanks!

Comment: I've done all this and I can't seem to get any thumbnail to show. Any, not just video. This happen after I deleted the .thumbnails folder, I see that they are being created inside that folder but nautilus is not showing them

Comment: In 12.10 I have to install `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` to get it work with nautilus.

Comment: Is Totem install really necessary, @Sukarn ?

Comment: Last command (to remove thumbnails that failed to load) was __my__ problem. Thanks

Comment: Just followed this with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using the Unity DM and it worked exactly as described. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions in [this forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1801173) and it worked perfectly.

Install libxine1-ffmpeg.
`sudo apt-get install libxine1-ffmpeg`

Then to force nautilus to generate new thumbnails execute
`rm -r ~/.thumbnails/fail

rm -r ~/.thumbnails/normal

killall -9 nautilus`

These commands will remove (delete) thumbnails from these folders.

Open nautilus again and you should be able to see thumbnails for all your videos.

Answer (score 0):

I had to re install my ubuntu to get the video thumbnails working again, it was annoying. I couldn't fin any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I installed `ffmpegthumbnailer`:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly totem libxine1-ffmpeg
```

It works in 13.10