# Some thumbnail previews not displaying

Tags: nautilus, totem, thumbnails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t generate video thumbnails in Nautilus [Ubuntu 12.04]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160971/cant-generate-video-thumbnails-in-nautilus-ubuntu-12-04)

I'm running 12.04 and have noticed that the only thing that displays a thumbnail preview are image files and not video files or anything else.  It's the video files portion that irks me the most.

I already have thumbnail preview turned on in display settings as well for all files, nothing helps.

Thanks in advance!!!