# Nautilus not generating thumbnails in 13.10

Tags: nautilus, 13.10, thumbnails

Like the title says, Nautilus is not generating thumbnails for any file types (pictures, documents, pdf, etc) after a clean install of 13.10.  I have checked the preferences and it is set to always generate thumbnails.

Help please!

Comment: New install, or upgrade (from 13.04) ?

Comment: Here's a rather accurate solution for 13.10 and all past versions: http://askubuntu.com/a/179107/17065
Note the change in path from '.thumbnails' to '.cache/thumbnails'

Answer (score 7):

I solved the problem by deleting whole folder thumbnails in `~/.cache` and remaking it.

1. Disable preview in nautilus by opening home folder, Edit-> Preferences-> Preview.
2. `sudo rm ~/.cache/thumbnails`
3. Empty trash can
4. `mkdir ~/.cache/thumbnails`
5. Reboot
6. Enable preview, again home folder, Edit-> Preferences-> Preview.

Done.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. It's important to follow every step

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue arises from the fact that the /home/x/.cache/thumbnails is owned by root, not by the actual user...

Hence rather than setting it to chmod 777, all you need to do is to "sudo chown [username] /home/[username]/.cache/thumbnails"

The above solves the problem for me.

Comment: This isn't always true, but in past versions the folder was '.thumbnails' insteaad of '.cache/thumbnails'

Answer (score 0):

If you run as sudo (IE launch terminal and command 'sudo nautilus') do you get thumbnails? It works for me when when ran as sudo, but only as sudo. I have installed webupd8's Unity patched Nemo, but it has the same symptoms (preview of media files fail unless ran as sudo).

I resolved this (rather worked around this bug) by running 'sudo chmod -R 777 /home/x/.cache/thumbnails/'. 777 is required (tried all other combos that make sense, but only 777 works). You will likely have to set up a script to run that occasionally...

Before resolving this issue please check to see if gnome bug 711220 is relevant! https://bugzilla.gnome.org/process_bug.cgi

IE if you open your pictures folder (or other directory with lots of previewable items), then run the command 'top', is nautilus using high cpu? If so and you navigate to a different folder (without previewable items) does that relieve nautilus's cpu utilization?

If it does PLEASE, PLEASE, PLEASE, confirm that bug!

Answer (score 0):

In my case Nautilus did not create thumbnails for any images but for videos. Turns out that after an upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 bionic and Ubuntu 18.10 cosmic the default thumbnailer was simply missing. You can check the current installed thumbnailers and their supported MIME types by

```
 cat /usr/share/thumbnailers/*
```

Using `apt-file search /usr/share/thumbnailers/` I looked for packages providing thumbnailers and it turned out that a simple

```
 sudo apt install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin
```

fixed my issue.

Answer (score -3):

It is easy!

open terminal and copy and paste:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R ~/.cache/thumbnails
```

Ready!

Comment: This solution sounds a bit strange to me, especially considering it is a clean install?