# Ubuntu 14.10 folder icons missing

Tags: icons

Ok, so I have searched and searched and cannot figure out what I did here. Most of my mp3, Libre Office, pdf, etc. files have missing icons. they look like this:
[image]

However if I access my network storage, I have exact copies of the same files in the photos btw, and they have the correct icons and look like

[image]

I am relatively new to Ubuntu, and I am sure that I did something wrong, but I have the system set up pretty much how I would like it for work and such, and would really hate to do a reinstall just for icons...

So if anyone could help it would be GREAT!

Comment: Seems like the directory is still loading, and.. both seem to be network locations (smb)

Comment: I see that now that you point it out... but its in the music folder that is in my home folder...

Comment: aldo just to add, this is not a new problem, I have experienced this issue for several weeks, through multiple reboots and cache clearings.

Comment: Do you have a separate `/home` partition? What does `grep /home /etc/fstab` say about `/home`?

Comment: Am I supposed to just input 'grep /home /etc/fstab' into terminal?

Comment: indeed, that's it :)

Comment: I did that and it returned nothing.

Comment: That means you don't have a separate home directory.

Comment: I found the answer [here.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/372817/nautilus-not-generating-thumbnails-in-13-10) Thank you Jacob Vlijm for your help, you were correct in that the thumbnails were not loading.