# Thumbnails in nautilus in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, nautilus

After upgrading to 13.10, nautilus stopped producing and showing thumbnail icons for images and videos.

Also in KDE environment, there's no longer a standard icon for nautilus in start menu (or its submenus).

How should I solve these problems with nautilus.

**Edit:**

[image]

‌
‌Before upgrading both could have proper thumbnails.

Comment: Could you add a screen-shot of the first problem? For the second ,you may need to create or edit a launcher file.

Comment: added‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.

Comment: Here's a rather accurate solution for 13.10 and all past versions: http://askubuntu.com/a/179107/17065
Note the change in path from '.thumbnails' to '.cache/thumbnails'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one, you just may need to edit the settings:
[image: Select preferences]
[image: Preferences Dialog]

If that fails, you may need to install the programs to thumbnail the files:

```
apt-get install....
```

Probably atleast one of these - *at a guess* *(**EDIT:** this was for Ubuntu 13.04/10 - you can search [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com) for thumbnailer packages - e.g. [for 16.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=yakkety&section=all&arch=any&keywords=thumbnail&searchon=names))*:

```
gnome-sushi - file previewer 
libnautilus-extension1a - libraries for nautilus components - runtime version
nautilus-actions - nautilus extension to configure programs to launch
libthumbnailer-dev - development files for thumbnailer
libthumbnailer0 - generate thumbnails from files
gnome-exe-thumbnailer - Wine .exe and other executable thumbnailer for Gnome
gnome-raw-thumbnailer - RAW file thumbnailer for GNOME 
ooo-thumbnailer - thumbnailer for OpenOffice.org documents
kde-thumbnailer-deb - KDE plugin to show thumbnails of Debian package files
kdegraphics-strigi-plugins - transitional package for kdegraphics-related plugins
kdegraphics-thumbnailers - graphics file format thumbnailers for KDE SC
ffmpegthumbnailer - fast and lightweight video thumbnailer
ffmpegthumbnailer-dbg - debugging informations for ffmpegthumbnailer
ffmpegthumbs - video thumbnail generator using ffmpeg
```

---

For your second problem, remove this line from `/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop` *(The launcher file for Nautilus - **EDIT:** For newer versions of Ubuntu use `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` instead of `nautilus.desktop`)*  :

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

You can edit it using nano for the entire system:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

or preferably for the current user:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
nano /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

Comment: It was solved. thnx.

Comment: Updated with answer and a guess for first problem - even though you may have solved it anyway.

Comment: Editing files in `/usr/share` is generally best avoided, since they can be overwritten by the package manager; copying .desktop files to `~/.local/share/applications` and editing them there is more reliable. This should cause the system copy of the .desktop file to be ignored. http://askubuntu.com/a/117526/309061

Comment: @GKFX - thanks I know that now but apparently not 3 years ago :)