# MPEG2 Transport Stream (MTS) Thumbnails

Tags: nautilus, video, thumbnails

I have one of these Sony handycams that produce MTS video files. Openshot can now edit them and MPlayer2 can play them, which is fantastic. But I have trouble knowing which is which in the file manager and Shotwell - as all the thumbnails are green or grey.

I have installed all the packages recommended in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160971/cant-generate-thumbnails-in-nautilus) and I have followed the instructions to add a custom MTS schema to the Gnome config in [this post](http://timsubuntuhowtos.blogspot.co.nz/2010/03/mts-avchd-and-nautilus-thumbnails.html), but still no result.

Answer (score 0):

I've a package workarounding the gray thumbnails problem for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS users. Please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/shotwell/+bug/1406546/comments/1 for how to upgrade to it.